# Bash script for loop ls exclude

Tags: bash

I am having some issues on my script

Original Script

```
SkipList="ldap|backup"
cd $BaseDir

for accountfolder in `ls | grep -v output | egrep "Account|HR|IT|Lawyer|2mft"`
do
    cd $BaseDir
    if [ "`echo $accountfolder | egrep -i \"$SkipList\"`" = "" ]
    then
       case $accountfolder in
       "Account")
          Stream="Account"
          AccountList="`ls Account |grep 2mft`"
          ;;
       "HR")
          Stream="HR"
          AccountList="`ls HR |grep 2mft`"
          ;;
       "IT")
          Stream="IT"
          AccountList="`ls IT |grep 2mft`"
          ;;
       "Lawyer")
          Stream="Lawyer"
          AccountList="`ls Lawyer |grep 2mft`"
          ;;
       *)
          Stream=""
          AccountList=$accountfolder
          ;;
       esac

       for account in $AccountList
       do
          cd ${BaseDir}/${Stream}/${account}
          for subfolder in `ls |grep -v output `
          do
              > $ErrTmpFile
              cd ${BaseDir}/${Stream}/${account}/${subfolder}
```

This script will scan all folder under BaseDir, but some of Directory already obsolete and cannot delete due to audit purpose.

Therefore, I generate active account and folder list to exclude inactive accounts & folders (from database level). How should I exclude those inactive from my scripts using the following list?

### List generate with Active status

```
HR/Billy
IT/Aa
etc....
```

How should I exclude those inactive from my scripts using the following list?

```
for accountfolder in `ls | grep -v output | egrep "Account|HR|IT|Lawyer|2mft"`
```

Comment: ***Never*** use `for i in $(ls anything)`, see [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) -- bad juju. (there is a reason that is **Pitfall No. 1**) Instead, use `find` to generate the list to iterate, using the `-max-depth` option if you need to limit the descent of the command. Since you are using bash, you can also feed your loop with *process substitution*, e.g. `while read -r accountfolder; do ... done < <(command that selects list)`

Comment: How do you tell which directories are `"already obsolete and cannot delete due to audit purpose"`?

Comment: Actually, this is java + database application with gui.
Some of the account disabled but cannot delete.
Therefore I sort out the list of current active accounts,

Comment: @David OK, let me change to while read